# align rows by date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

An excerpt of the Dateframe could look like this (it's certainly much larger):

```
            Date1        Log1     Date2     Log2    Date3       Log3   
 Index
   0       01.01.2000    1000   02.01.2000  2000   01.01.2000   3000
   1       02.01.2000    1050   03.01.2000  1950   02.01.2000   3020
   2       03.01.2000    1100   04.01.2000  2000   03.01.2000   3000
```

Is there a quick way to align the rows so that the dates (here in Columns `Date3` and `Log3`) match with those in column `Date1`?

```
            Date1        Log1     Date2     Log2    Date3       Log3   
 Index
   0       01.01.2000    1000   NaN                01.01.2000   3000
   1       02.01.2000    1050   02.01.2000  2000   02.01.2000   3020
   2       03.01.2000    1100   03.01.2000  1950   03.01.2000   3000
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is the intention that you only keep values from [Date2, Log2] and [Date3, Log3] that match dates in the Date1 column? In other words, should we completely drop the 04.01.2000 date from Date2?

Comment: @andrew, no, the date 04.01.2000 should not be dropped. The Index is longer than presented and final dates of all Logs match but they have different start dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `list comprehension` and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all data together:

```
dates = [col for col in df.columns if 'Date' in col]
logs = [col for col in df.columns if 'Log' in col]

print ([df[[col[0], col[1]]].set_index(col[0], drop=False)
                            .reindex(df.Date1) for col in zip(dates, logs)])

[                 Date1  Log1
Date1                       
01.01.2000  01.01.2000  1000
02.01.2000  02.01.2000  1050
03.01.2000  03.01.2000  1100,                  Date2    Log2
Date1                         
01.01.2000         NaN     NaN
02.01.2000  02.01.2000  2000.0
03.01.2000  03.01.2000  1950.0,                  Date3  Log3
Date1                       
01.01.2000  01.01.2000  3000
02.01.2000  02.01.2000  3020
03.01.2000  03.01.2000  3000]

df1 = pd.concat([df[[col[0], col[1]]]
        .set_index(col[0], drop=False)
        .reindex(df.Date1) for col in zip(dates, logs)], axis=1)

df1.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

print (df1)
        Date1  Log1       Date2    Log2       Date3  Log3
0  01.01.2000  1000         NaN     NaN  01.01.2000  3000
1  02.01.2000  1050  02.01.2000  2000.0  02.01.2000  3020
2  03.01.2000  1100  03.01.2000  1950.0  03.01.2000  3000
```

Comment: quite elegant,  the [df[[col[0], col[1]]].set_index(col[0], drop=False)    .reindex(df.Date1) for col in zip(dates, logs)]

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you only want to keep values from ['Date2', 'Log2'] and ['Date3', 'Log3'] when the dates have a match in Date1.

You can read the different columns into separate dataframes and use `merge`. Then filter to only keep rows where the Date1 column is not null.

```
df
>>>
        Date1  Log1       Date2  Log2       Date3  Log3
0  01.01.2000  1000  02.01.2000  2000  01.01.2000  3000
1  02.01.2000  1050  03.01.2000  1950  02.01.2000  3020
2  03.01.2000  1100  04.01.2000  2000  03.01.2000  3000

df1 = df[['Date1', 'Log1']]
df2 = df[['Date2', 'Log2']]
df3 = df[['Date3', 'Log3']]

df_out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on='Date1', right_on='Date2')
df_out = df_out.merge(df3, how='outer', left_on='Date1', right_on='Date3')
df_out = df_out[df_out['Date1'].notnull()]

df_out
>>>
        Date1    Log1       Date2    Log2       Date3    Log3
0  01.01.2000  1000.0         NaN     NaN  01.01.2000  3000.0
1  02.01.2000  1050.0  02.01.2000  2000.0  02.01.2000  3020.0
2  03.01.2000  1100.0  03.01.2000  1950.0  03.01.2000  3000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary to represent your data, this is just a convenience to load the sample data to dataframe.

```
d = {'Date1': {0: '01.01.2000', 1: '02.01.2000', 2: '03.01.2000'}, 'Date3': {0: '01.01.2000', 1: '02.01.2000', 2: '03.01.2000'}, 'Date2': {0: '02.01.2000', 1: '03.01.2000', 2: '04.01.2000'}, 'Log2': {0: 2000, 1: 1950, 2: 2000}, 'Log3': {0: 3000, 1: 3020, 2: 3000}, 'Log1': {0: 1000, 1: 1050, 2: 1100}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df[['Date1','Log1','Date2','Log2','Date3','Log3']]
df.index.names = ['Index']

print df
```

**Starting Dataframe:**

```
            Date1  Log1       Date2  Log2       Date3  Log3
Index                                                      
0      01.01.2000  1000  02.01.2000  2000  01.01.2000  3000
1      02.01.2000  1050  03.01.2000  1950  02.01.2000  3020
2      03.01.2000  1100  04.01.2000  2000  03.01.2000  3000
```

This is crude but does the job:

```
list_dfs = []
for i in range(1,4):
    column_subset =  [col for col in df.columns if str(i) in col]
    df_subset_columns =  df[column_subset]
    df_subset_columns.columns = ['Date','Log']
    df_subset_columns['id'] = i
    list_dfs.append(df_subset_columns)

df =  pd.concat(list_dfs,axis=0,ignore_index=True)

df = df.set_index(['Date','id'])
df = df.unstack('id')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

At this point I think this is what you are looking logically:

```
id             1     2     3
Date                        
01.01.2000 1,000   nan 3,000
02.01.2000 1,050 2,000 3,020
03.01.2000 1,100 1,950 3,000
04.01.2000   nan 2,000   nan
```

But to revert back to the desired output

```
list_dfs = []
for i in range(1,4):
    df_s = df[i].to_frame()
    df_s.columns = ['Log' + str(i)]
    print df_s
    list_dfs.append(df_s.reset_index())

print pd.concat(list_dfs,axis=1)
```